# Configuring Eclipse for ROS

Tags: eclipse, ros

I am new to Linux. I am trying to develop ROS application using eclipse. I don't understand the below which is provided in [ROS website](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Reusing_your_shell.27s_environment). Can you explain this in more simple way, So that I can configure my eclipse after downloading from eclipse.org.

> ### Reusing your shell's environment
>
> For building and running ROS programs from inside IDEs, the ROS
>   enviroment has to be set up. All IDEs might have a config for that,
>   but **running your IDE from your ROS-sourced shell** should be the easiest
>   way, avoiding inconsistency.
>
> Likewise, you can enhance your IDE's launcher icon to load your shells
>   environment. E.g., replace its command eclipse with
>   `bash -i -c "eclipse"`. This will make bash source
>   `~/.bashrc`, in which ROS has to
>   be sourced and parameterized, and start that IDE.

Comment: what did you try ? what errors did you get ?

Answer (score 6):

use following commands:

```
cd <your_catkin_workspace>
catkin_make --force-cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"
cd build
cmake ../src -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

now you can import your project to eclipse

after that you can create a desktop application entry for eclispe:

sudo vim /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=<path_to_your_eclipse_dir>/icon.xpm
Exec=bash -i -c "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash && source $HOME/workspace/<your_catkin_workspace>/devel/setup.bash && <path_to_your_eclipse_dir>/eclipse"
Comment=IDE
Name=eclipse
Comment=IDE
```

Comment: After that you can
    nautilus /usr/share/applications/
and drag your eclipse.desktop file to Ubuntu launcher

Answer (score 2):

It seems that a wiki was published about this subject [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs)

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, the lines you listed are suggesting you run your IDE (eclipse) from a terminal which has already been `source`d. So for instance, if you have a package called mypackage, you might type in a terminal:

```
    cd ~/mypackage
    source devel/setup.bash
    eclipse
```

The first line is just however you get to your package, the second line sets up environmental variables for you (like changing your PATH), then you can run eclipse with all of those already setup so you don't have to configure your package in eclipse 100% manually.